# Including uic auto generated header files in .cpp file

Tags: ros, include, headers, header, qt4

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may seem like a very stupid question, but I have a QT project that is built using rosbuild and CMake. The ui_form.h file is generated in the CMake build directory. I need to include this file in form.cpp to be able to access my buttons so I currently have (form.cpp is in a src subdirectory):

```
#include "../build/ui_form.h"
```

Is this the best way to do it since the build path could change? I could not think of any other way to do it, but I am sure I am missing something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56684/including-uic-auto-generated-header-files-in-.cpp-file/) by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just encountered this when moving a package from catkin to rosbuild.

The solution I used was to add the line:

```
include_directories(include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
```

to the CMakeLists.txt

Then you'd be able to include your file as such:

```
#include "ui_form.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [GreatSuccess](https://answers.ros.org/users/9526/greatsuccess/) with karma: 78 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0